# Car is overheating sometimes (Suzuki Liana 2003)

Tags: troubleshooting, overheating

In the beginning please excuse my English as its not my mother tongue.

I have a suzuki Liana 2003 model and it was purchased from the dealer on 2004. I intend to keep it running for as long as I can.

the issue started in 2014 when I went to a garage to fill the compressor with gas as the AC was not cooling and he is someone I usually go to the past years before the issue. up until that moment I never new what is overheating meant. the car was perfectly fine. after the technician filled the compressor with gas and AC was cool, the technician closed the bonnet and I went home. on my way home the AC started to become hot and I suddenly notice a red sign from the dashboard and I know its an overheating sign. I parked at the side of the road turned off the car and opened the bonnet. the hood support rod was dislocated and it penetrated the radiator and caused the coolant to exit.

since then up until now Im having the car overheats.

what have bin done over the past years:

1- the car overheated 10s of times.
2- replaced the radiator with a good branded one similar to the original (known brand in my country)
3- replaced the radiator cap
4- replaced the hoses 
5- replaced the temp sensor
6- replaced the thermostat and it was in a very difficult place (rear/below the engine)
7- replaced the water pump and signs or leakage was in the previous one.
8- replaced the radiator motor and it was very expensive (gamble)
9- replaced the radiator fan relays just in case they where the issue.

all above parts except the radiator are Suzuki genuine parts from the dealer it self.

10- tried to check if the head gasket was the reason so I used the chemical tester placed at the radiator cap and it didn't change color so I assumed the head gas kit is fine.
11- purchased endoscope and removed all spark plugs and checked all 4 Combustion chambers for any coolant inside after the car was ideally for 30 days + without ignition because I noticed the coolant in the overflow tank was sucked which is normal when the car cools off but just to narrow down the issue.

now its better then before i can drive normally in small area without a problem but if I went to a far city the car will end up overheating specially in summer where it reach 52degC (125degF).
I notice when the car is heating that the overflow take is filled and it overflows.
I purchased the Radiator Coolant Filling Funnel Kit to make sure all air is out of the system as I hear bubbles from inside the car sometimes when accelerating. at some point there was no bubble sounds and the car still overheats randomly.

Im very tired and I dont want to loss this car as its very special to me.

Please if there is any more suggestion it will help as I really think its the head gasket is the only thing remains and I dont think the test I made was correct.

Comment: Test the coolant to ind out if there are combustion products in it.

Comment: Sure will repeat the test for combustion gases in the coolant again and see if it will change colors. maybe I did it wrong the first time.